# unsupported-text-language exception in AlchemyAPI?

Tags: alchemyapi

I'm using AlchemyAPI "AlchemyAPI.TextGetTaxonomy(String)" method and it's returning exception: "unsupported-text-language". My input is: "factorial carrot".

Please advise where to set language ? My preferred language is "English".

Your response is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Vlad for your help.

I'm doing REST calls and after testing and debugging, this issues is fixed finally.

If anyone facing same problem (using REST call) then just set:

```
data.append("&language=english");
```

in class:

```
com.alchemyapi.api.AlchemyAPI
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an SDK or Rest calls? 
If you are using the Java SDK, the following thread helped me out with the same type of problem, but for a different service: [Github Issue 1](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/issues/64#issuecomment-206627153)

Basically it suggests to set the "language" paramater to "english".

> params.put("language", "english");

I believe this can be adapted for any SDK or Rest Call.

I find it strange that this parameter is not specified in the documentation, nor in the Java SDK Constants, but it works.

**UPDATE:**

Apparently newer versions of the java SDK have a `setLanguage()`
 method. Source [Github Issue 2](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/issues/204#issuecomment-223894923)

Example:

```
final AlchemyLanguage service = new AlchemyLanguage();
service.setLanguage(LanguageSelection.ENGLISH); // <--

final Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put(AlchemyLanguage.TEXT, "delete laboratory record");
final SAORelations relations = service.getRelations(params).execute();
```

Comment: P.S. A few extra tags could help out this question to get a better ranking.